# angular2 javascript keyup simultaneous method calls to last keystroke call

Tags: javascript, performance, angular

angular2 following is the example of code i have

i have attached onFormChange() method on every keystroke over the form which is filtering objects to make sure there are valid form on each row.

`setTimeout(()=> this.findChange(), 1000 );` fires every second.

1. prevent multiple executions of findChange() method and execute only when user take a pause on keystrokes.

```
    private onFormChange(isValid: boolean, myObject){

       myObject.valid= isValid;
       setTimeout(()=> this.findChange(), 1000 );

        }
   private findChange(){
    global_var_change_found = this.objects.filter(
      myObject=> myObject.valid && myObject.ready ).length > 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `changeTimeout` reference and clear it before setting new one:

```
 private onFormChange(isValid: boolean, myObject){

       myObject.valid= isValid;

       clearTimeout(this.changeTimeout);

       this.changeTimeout = setTimeout(()=> this.findChange(), 1000 );

        }
   private findChange(){
    global_var_change_found = this.objects.filter(myObject=> myObject.valid && myObject.ready ).length > 0
}
```

Note that this is quickfix for your solution. I suggest to use Observables. Dealing with this kind of problems are much more comfortable.

Here's simple example:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
  .map(() => input.value)
.debounceTime(1000)
  .subscribe(
    results => {
      
      //Do Whatever You want here.
      
      console.log("Do whatever you want here");
      
    },
    error => { console.log(error); }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Comment: i can still go for observables, would you suggest any quick code sample for that ?

Comment: sorry didn't found any observable in ans